# How do I omit ModelAttribute parameters from the ModelAndView returned by a Spring 3 MVC action?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC controller with an action that's called using AJAX.

```
@SessionAttributes({"userContext"})
public class Controller
{
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/my-url", method= { RequestMethods.POST })
    public ModelAndView doSomething(@ModelAttribute("userContext") UserContext context,
            SessionStatus sessionStatus)
    {
        BusinessObject obj = doSomeBusinessLogic(context.getUserName());
        sessionStatus.setComplete();
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("jsonView");
        mav.addObject("someInt", obj.getId());
        return mav;
    }
}
```

When I run this action, I get the following exception:

```
net.sf.json.JSONException: There is a cycle in the hierarchy!
at t.sf.json.util.CycleDetectionStrategy$StrictCycleDetectionStrategy.handleRepeatedReferenceAsObject(CycleDetectionStrategy.java:97)
at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:833)
at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:168)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.writer.jsonlib.PropertyEditorRegistryValueProcessor.processObjectValue(PropertyEditorRegistryValueProcessor.java:127)
at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromMap(JSONObject.java:1334)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

After doing some debugging I found out that Spring is placing the UserContext object onto the ModelAndView that I am returning.  If I hard-code my user name and remove the context object from the method's parameters, the action runs successfully.  Is there a way to configure Spring to omit the ModelAttribute-annotated parameters from the returned ModelAndView?  As you can see, `sessionStatus.setComplete()` has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I registered a `WebArgumentResolver` to get to my session variable.  This allowed me to keep this session variable out of the response while keeping my action unit testable.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems in the past with `@SessionAttributes`. By declaring `@SessionAttributes({"userContext"})` you're telling Spring that you want `"userContext"` to always be available in the model, and so Spring has no choice but to send your `UserContext` object out to the model, just in case you're going to be redirecting or doing something else which might end up at another `Controller`.

The "solution" (and I didn't like it much, but it worked) was to omit the `@SessionAttributes` annotation on the controller, add an `HttpSession` parameter to the necessary methods and "manually" manage what's in it.

I'm interested to see if there's a better way, because it seems `@SessionAttributes` has tremendous potential to tidy up controller-level code.

Answer (score 0):

Along with @ModelAttribute, pass @ModelMap as a method argument.
Based on business logic, error conditions -- if you do not need the attribute for certain scenarios, then remove it from the map.

```
    public ModelAndView foo(@ModelAttribute("userContext") UserContext, @ModelMap map){
      if(success){
       return success.jsp
      }
      else{
       map.remove("userContext");
      return "error.jsp" 
      }
    }
```

Not totally satisfied with having to pass the ModelMap as well, but I did not find any other easier way of doing it.

Cheers!!